# How to ensure exactly vertical/horizontal connectors between identical size and aligned shapes?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, diagrams

I create a shape and duplicate it, then connect them with an angular connector line.

Then I decided to placed them in a vertical line, expecting the connector to become one straight line, but it shows with a tiny "step".

I know I could use the straight connector line, but I would like to use just one type of connector everywhere in my diagram, because the next second I might have to move the shape somewhere else, and don't want to change the type all the time.

Update:
I am looking for a solution that does not require me to break the alignment and/or change the sizes of the shapes.

[image]  [image]

Answer (score 14):

Quoting from [PowerPoint Tip: Fix Your Crooked Lines](http://hauteslides.com/2011/04/powerpoint-tip-fix-your-crooked-lines/) :

> When you click the line go to the Format Tab in the ribbon and look at the Size option. On the right you can see that the line above has a height of .05″. Well that’s not the stroke (thickness) of the line. This number actually denotes the height difference in the location of the starting point and ending point of the line. Which means that the end point.

So, what you have to do is to set the parameter that determines the offset (width for vertical lines and vice versa) to 0. Note that it might already say 0, in that case input it again manually et voilà!

Comment: On Mac, it worked in 'Shape Format' tab and setting 'Height' to 0

Comment: Yep this works great! But the question remains: If I have two identical shapes, aligned top, same height, and I connect using their connection points, why is the line offset?

Answer (score 5):

Even when "snap to grid" is enabled, it will sometimes put the offset in the connector.

You can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for fine adjustment.

1. Select your shape, hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
2. Move the shape left or right with the arrow keys.

This will move it a fraction of what it normally would if you press an arrow key.

NOTE: If it doesn't work immediately, the shapes may be too close together vertically. You may have to move the shapes farther apart vertically to get the connector completely straight, then move the shapes back together.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but if the only solution means to move the shapes away from the correct alignment, then I'd prefer to change the connection type to straight (it's even less clicks).

Comment: If this answered your question, even if you choose not to use it, please check it as being the answer. Someone else may find it useful.

Comment: I did not accept your answer because it involves breaking the alignment of the shapes. And accepting would imply that I went with your solution, which I did not. Someone else should still be able to find it useful, though.

Comment: I hear what you're saying and I'm OK with that even though you did not state "breaking the alignment" was unacceptable. For the future reference, keep in mind when you give a criteria in your question, like "I know I could use the straight connector line, but I would like to use just one type of connector everywhere in my diagram", in most cases your going to get answers which meet the criteria. Even if the answer is not what you were hoping for, you should acknowledge the effort made by others to help you by selecting the best answer. With that being said, best wishes with your PPT project.

Comment: I gave you an upvote for your efforts. But the fact remains that I have yet to discover an acceptable solution to this problem.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question to include the additional criteria which you require.